# Remove inner divs from a parent div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Consider my parent div is `parentDiv` and it contains five child divs

```
<div id="parentDiv">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
</div>
```

How to empty the child elements `parentDiv`  using jquery....

**EDIT**:

What is the diff between `empty()` and `remove()`? what should i use?

Comment: if you have some text enclosed in parentDiv. $("#parentDiv").empty() will flush it, $("#parentDiv div").remove() wont, it's up to you to decide which behavior you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#parentDiv").empty();` from [here](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `$("#parentDiv div").remove()` or `$("#parentDiv").empty()` ?

Answer (score 3):

`.empty()` removes all of the children of the selected element(s); `.remove()` removes the selected element(s) themselves as well as any children.

Thus, `$("#parentdiv").empty();` makes the most sense here, because you want to remove the children but not the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` removes all the child nodes of the matched selector, whereas `remove()` removes the matched selector.

Answer (score 1):

`remove` removes the element itself from the DOM (in this case #parentDiv) whereas `empty` is equivilent to calling `$('#parentDiv').children().remove();` and removes all of the elements children.

In this case you should use `empty`:

```
$('#parentDiv').empty()
```